# How to convert this string into Datetime + See difference between this datetime and current time

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

Hey looking to convert this string into datetime

```
20101119T162837
```

And then also how to compare this string to current time so I can say, i.e:

30 Mins difference or 2 hours 10 min difference etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DateTime.ParseExact()...

```
var strValue = "20101119T162837";

var dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(strValue, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
var diff = dateValue - DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("difference: {0:HH}h{0:mm}", diff);
```

edit: I'm not sure about the default format so you can try the simple Parse method first like George Stocker recommended

Comment: You could just do DateTime.ParseExact("20101119T162837", "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
And not require the replace... otherwise beat me to it...

Comment: yep i wasn't sure the 'T' wasn't going to mess up the format so I used the safe way edit: just seen your quotes

Comment: How can I do this var diff = dateValue - DateTime.Now;
in VB.NET ?

Comment: I'm not sure, dateValue.Substract(DateTime.Now) or Add(-xxx)?

Comment: DateTime.Now.Substract(dataValue) will return a TimeSpan that will give you the difference between the two date values.

Answer (score 0):

Guillaume86's code in Visual Basic

```
    Dim strValue As String = "20101119T162837"

    Dim dateValue As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strValue, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    Dim diff As TimeSpan = dateValue - DateTime.Now
```